# What is the best available way to take substrate DB backup without stopping the service?

Tags: database, snapshot

I have the substrate setup on AWS EC2 with EBS volume attached to it. I wonder what would be the best way to take substrate DB backup.

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to just backup the Database folder. Normally that is located in `.local/share/` depending on which chain you use there is a sub-folder. You can change the location with the `-d` flag.

Another possibility is to use the block export and import, but it is much slower.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have edited the question. I need to take a backup without stopping the service. AFAIK, taking a folder backup without stopping a service is not a good idea.